# Accessing the ID of an HTML element in a different aspx file to then be used in the other file's code-behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have 2 aspx files. Let's call the first P1 and the second P2. In P1, I have an HTML element with ID "date". I want to access date in P2's code-behind C# file, but am unsure how to do this. I'm using Visual Studio.

Must I use "using P1.aspx" in P2's code-behind file? Must I declare an object of P1 in P2's code-behind file?

For example, in P2's code-behind file, why can't I do the following:

P1 object = new P1();
object.date = ...;

As of now I can't get P1 to be recognized by P2 in any way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a disconnect in an aspx page life-cycle here.  What if a user has never been to page P1?  If they had you would have to store the values in session or somewhere else once you navigated to P2 to be able to utilize them.

Comment: David Yenglin, the "date" must be chosen in P1 to then be used in P2.

Comment: In order to share the date set in P1 with P2 you will need to redirect to P2 and set in the query string a variable for the date.  Then when P2 loads it will use the query string to load up the page with the date.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve using  CrossPagePostBack...for More Info..You can refer this Link..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178139(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

For Example:- 
P1.aspx

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRedirect" runat="server" Text="Redirect" OnClick="btnRedirect_Click"/>

  protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/P2.aspx");
    }
```

Suppose...Your P1 page contain TextBox(txtDate) thats you want to access in P2.aspx Page
You can redirect to other page using CrossPagePostBack...

In P2.aspx Page on Page Load event you can easily find out Previous Page Control..

```
  if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("txtDate");
        }
```

**For More Info....**

Suppose your PreviousPage i.e. P1.aspx have master control Page Property...then you can use this..on P2.aspx Page...

```
 if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            Control ContentPlaceHolder1 = this.Page.PreviousPage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("txtDate");
        }
```